# Creating a zip file with C# more efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, io, compression, azure-appservice

**Short Version**

Is there a more efficient or less-resource-intensive way in C# to create a zip file of a folder recursively than using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`?

**Long Version**

I have a REST API running in an Azure App Service (Scaled at P2V2 420 total ACU and 7 GB memory). One of my endpoints accepts a POST request and generates a zip file using the following code. It then returns the name of the zip file that was generated wrapped in a standard JSON format.

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, outputPath);
```

This runs fine on my local machine, but appears to have scaling issues on the cloud server. When I scale up to the next level app service (P3V2 820 ACU, 14GB memory) it runs fine, but without scaling up the API returns a 503 Service Unavailable message. I am not sure which resource is constrained (cpu, memory, disk, etc.), but I don't think it's a server timeout issue since it only runs about 10-20 seconds. The zip file generated is roughly 400 files or 200MB compressed.

My question is, since scaling up costs an extra $120 per month, is there a way to generate a zip file more efficiently so I don't need to scale up the server? Would it help at all to split the zip file creation into creating and adding files steps, using multiple commands rather than using `CreateFromDirectory(...)`?

Other info:

- This endpoint is not being hit by anyone but me
- I can try to create multiple smaller zip files to see if this helps with resource consumption, but this is not ideal for my use case.
- This is not the only thing running on this server which is why it's already scaled up so much
- Just to clarify, the zip file does actually get created on the server and I am able to see a log entry that gets logged just before response goes back to the user, and I can see the zip file in kudu. But Azure intercepts the 200 API response for some reason and sends a 503 instead.

Comment: Did CreateFromDirectory throw any exception when you received 503 status code?

Comment: Did you try different CompressionLevel?

Comment: I use winrar console version for this (from C# code). Very performant & stable.

Comment: First you need to determine what the problem is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

Comment: No exception was thrown. I was able to log a message after everything completed just before the response was sent back from the server. I haven't tried a different compression level. Will look into that too. Thank you TheGeneral for the resource. I'll check it out.

Comment: how are you determining the source/dest directory?  does this occur when more than one user collides on a directory?  are you cleaning up when done?  have you considered using streams so you dont have to save the uploaded (or downloaded) data to disk at all?